# How to count and group by in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I would like to generate following query using yii2:

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM lead WHERE approved = 1 GROUP BY promoter_location_id, lead_type_id`

I have tried:

```
$leadsCount = Lead::find()
->where('approved = 1')
->groupBy(['promoter_location_id', 'lead_type_id'])
->count();
```

Which generates this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM `lead` WHERE approved = 1 GROUP BY `promoter_location_id`, `lead_type_id`) `c`
```

In yii 1.x I would've done the following:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = 'COUNT(*) AS cnt';
$criteria->group = array('promoter_location_id', 'lead_type_id');
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can use create command to write your mysql query

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Solution:

```
$leadsCount = Lead::find()
->select(['COUNT(*) AS cnt'])
->where('approved = 1')
->groupBy(['promoter_location_id', 'lead_type_id'])
->all();
```

and add `public $cnt` to the model, in my case Lead.

As Kshitiz also stated, you could also just use `yii\db\Query::createCommand()`.

Comment: This works and I had to add the public variable to the model class and mentioned by @deacs  and replace the all() method with `->createCommand()->queryAll();` Also note that my select() method has multiples `->select(['type, date(significant_timestamp) AS significant_timestamp, COUNT(*) AS size'])`

Answer (score 9):

You can get the count by using **count()** in the select Query

```
$leadCount = Lead::find()
->where(['approved'=>'1'])
->groupBy(['promoter_location_id', 'lead_type_id'])
->count();
```

[Reference Link](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/select-query-model/#count) for various functions of select query

Answer (score 8):

If you are just interested in the count, use `yii\db\Query` as mentioned by others. Won't require any changes to your model:

```
$leadsCount = (new yii\db\Query())
    ->from('lead')
    ->where('approved = 1')
    ->groupBy(['promoter_location_id', 'lead_type_id'])
    ->count();
```

Here's a link to the [Yii2 API documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#count%28%29-detail)

Answer (score 4):

Without adding the `$cnt` property to model

```
$leadsCount = Lead::find()
->select(['promoter_location_id', 'lead_type_id','COUNT(*) AS cnt'])
->where('approved = 1')
->groupBy(['promoter_location_id', 'lead_type_id'])
->createCommand()->queryAll();
```

Comment: Please do not merely post code but also add a few words explaining what the pivotal difference is.

Comment: But we get not ActiveRecords as a result

Comment: Yes. This query will not return the ActiveRecords since you define the ->select(['promoter_location_id', 'lead_type_id','COUNT(*) AS cnt'])

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, in case it helps anyone, that a getter used as a property is countable (whereas if called as a function it will return 1). In this example, I have a Category class with Listings joined by listing_to_category.  To get Active, Approved Listings for the Category, I return an ActiveQuery, thus:

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getListingsApprovedActive() {
        return $this->hasMany(Listing::className(), ['listing_id' => 'listing_id'])
                                ->viaTable('listing_to_category', ['category_id' => 'category_id'])
                                ->andWhere(['active' => 1])->andWhere(['approved' => 1]);
}
```

Calling count on the property of the Category will return the record count:

```
count($oCat->listingsApprovedActive)
```

Calling count on the function will return 1:

```
count($oCat->getListingsApprovedActive())
```