# Migrating from Mysql to Postgresql Yii2 query

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, yii2

Before, we were using mysql for our database but when we migrated to postgresql we encountered this problem.

`SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "table.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM "kv_firmw...
^
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM "kv_firmware_release" ORDER BY "id" DESC) "table" GROUP BY "filename") "c"`

I have this code in Yii2 search model.

```
    $subquery = new Query;   
    $subquery->select(['*']);
    $subquery->from('kv_firmware_release')->orderBy('id DESC');

    $query = new Query;
    $query->select(['*']);
    $query->from(['table' => $subquery])->groupBy('filename');

    $query->limit(5);
```

This is my first time to use Psql. It works fine before, but now it is giving me the error. How can I fix this in Yii2?

Comment: $query->select(['*'])->groupBy('filename') does not make sense in mysql either. Group by filename but return all the fields? How is that suppose to make sense in any DB? It works but your results will be more or less random.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, with mysql is optional put all the columns in field list and group by clause, in postgres and other databases you must put all columns.

So when you are working with aggregates put in fields list the columns that you will use, avoid unnecessary fields.

Mysql exemple

```
SELECT id, name, email FROM contact GROUP BY id
```

In Postgres

```
SELECT id, name, email FROM contact GROUP BY id, name, email
```

Comment: thanks but I don't have an idea how I will do this in Yii2. Can you add more tips?

Comment: @Gibs first change the `*` in `$query->select(['*']);` for the name of columns and put the same list in `->groupBy('filename');` like, `->groupBy('id, filename');` or `->groupBy(['id', 'filename']);`

Comment: @Gibs [How to count and group by in yii2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24389765/1342547)

Comment: I am trying first this `select filename FROM (SELECT id, remarks, filename FROM "kv_firmware_release" ORDER BY "id" DESC) b group by (b.filename)` this worked but why does `select id, remarks, filename FROM (SELECT id, remarks, filename FROM "kv_firmware_release" ORDER BY "id" DESC) b group by (filename)` not work? I wanted to get id and remarks at the same time too. Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: error is `SQL error:

ERROR:  column "b.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select id, remarks, filename FROM (SELECT id, remarks, filen...
               ^
In statement:
select id, remarks, filename FROM (SELECT id, remarks, filename FROM "kv_firmware_release" ORDER BY "id" DESC) b group by (filename)`

Answer (score 0):

in PostgreSQL when use `group by` you must write all fields using in `select` or `unique or primary key`

**For example**

```
SELECT id, name, email FROM contact GROUP BY id, name, email
```

OR

```
SELECT id, name, email FROM contact GROUP BY id
```

wil work when column `id`  is `primary or unique key`